# what is the service-target name for the iOS Simulator Process

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I want add a dylib once launch a iOS Simulator App.
I know we coud do something like:

```
$ xcrun simctl spawn booted launchctl debug system/com.apple.SpringBoard --environment DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=path/to/dynamic/lib.dylib
```

this is good for com.apple.SpringBoard. but what is the service-target name for my own APP?